# Uninitialized constant in controller Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

This is the route:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw.do
devise_for :users do
collection do
  post 'batch_invite'
end
end
root 'welcome#index'

resources :rosters, only: [:index, :show]

end
```

My rosters controller:

```
class RostersController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @rosters = Roster.all.order("created_at_DESC")
  end
 end
```

My Index:

```
<div id="banner" class="roster_banner">
  <h1>View and create rosters</h1>
</div>

<div id="rosters" class="cf">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="cf">
      <% @rosters.each do |roster| %>
        <%= link_to roster do %>
          <li>

            <div class="roster_overview">
              <h2><%= roster.title %></h2>
              <p class="week_count">Week 1</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>

    <%= will_paginate @rosters, previous_label: "Previous", next_label: "Next" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't see anything wrong, but when I load localhost:3000/rosters I get:

```
Error: NameError (uninitialized constant RostersController::Roster):
  app/controllers/rosters_controller.rb:3:in `index'
```

Error that I get: uninitialized constant RostersController::Roster [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmn5S.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmn5S.png)  = screenshot of error

Comment: Please post the full error in the question.

Comment: Added a screen shot [1]

Comment: Do you have a file called `roster.rb` in `app/models`?

Comment: No, I don't, I presume I should?

Comment: Don't use screen shots for information that is essential to a question. We can't copy/paste information from a screen shot, nor can search engines use the image to index the page. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]"; We need the information in the question itself, not at the end of links that can rot and break.

Comment: I think I added the error now, again, sorry!

Comment: Yes you should have roster.rb as this is the class that will help you reach your rosters table. Are you familiar with rails generators for model classes?

Comment: I have roster.rb now but I get a different error,

ActionView::Template::Error (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: created_at_DESC: SELECT "rosters".* FROM "rosters"   ORDER BY created_at_DESC):
     5: <div id="rosters" class="cf">
     6:         <div class="wrapper">
     7:                 <ul class="cf">
     8:                         <% @rosters.each do |roster| %>
     9:                                 <%= link_to roster do %>
    10:                                         <li>
    11:
  app/views/rosters/index.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_rosters_index_html_erb___315297093_57160776

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> uninitialized constant RostersController::Roster

You should have a model file with the name `roster.rb` in `app/models`

```
#roster.rb

class Roster < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: I get another error when I create roster.rb        

       ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Rosters#index

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: rosters: SELECT "rosters".* FROM "rosters"   ORDER BY created_at_DESC

Comment: @AaronO'Leary That means now you should create a table called rosters in your db.

Comment: @AaronO'Leary Follow these guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: I did what you told me to do and it got me past the error, thanks! just have to create the show page! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Rails is very very mean at naming (for many good reasons). You must follow the rules like this (pay attention to the case and the singular/plural forms):

```
File name            | Class name | Table name
app/models/roster.rb | Roster     | rosters
```

Otherwise you will have errors.

Comment: I don't think I have any naming issues but I will go through it again after work and see, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Pavan's answer,

From the screenshot of your controller index action, this will not work 
`@rosters = Roster.all.order("created_at_DESC")`
Try this instead 
`@rosters = Roster.order('created_at': 'DESC')` ,
`@rosters = Roster.order("created_at DESC")` 
OR 
`@rosters = Roster.order(created_at: :desc)`

Also, `all` is not required with `order`.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order

Comment: Thank you for this! It saved me even more hassle! :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help :)